# CS50W mail project, mark my read variable in my API as true as default but it must be false

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, cs50

I've been dealing with this bug for past few days and i can't fix it. So basically in this project i should make a email in a local host server using only JS, HTML and css. as you can see in the following code the read variable of the emails that get composed must remain false as default until you visit the email page : models.py :

```
class Email(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="emails")
    sender = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="emails_sent")
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name="emails_received")
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "sender": self.sender.email,
            "recipients": [user.email for user in self.recipients.all()],
            "subject": self.subject,
            "body": self.body,
            "timestamp": self.timestamp.strftime("%b %d %Y, %I:%M %p"),
            "read": self.read,
            "archived": self.archived
        }
```

and it's not my JS file problem because i never even write anything for the read variable to change it : Inbox.js file :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  
  // Use buttons to toggle between views
  document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
  document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
  document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
  document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);
  document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', submit);

  // By default, load the inbox
  load_mailbox('inbox');
  
});

function compose_email() {

  // Show compose view and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#email-page').style.display = 'none';
  
  // Clear out composition fields
  const recipient = document.querySelector('#compose-recipients');
  const subject = document.querySelector('#compose-subject');
  const body = document.querySelector('#compose-body');
  document.querySelector('#compose-head').innerHTML = 'New Email';
  recipient.value = '';
  subject.value = '';
  body.value = '';
  recipient.disabled = false;
  subject.disabled = false;
  body.placeholder = 'Body';

}

function submit()
{
  fetch('/emails', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      recipients: document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value,
      subject: document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value,
      body: document.querySelector('#compose-body').value,
    }),
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .then(email => {
    console.log(email)
    alert('nice')
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error:', error)
  });
  
}
```

right after i submit which Function submit will be called , the read var of my sent mail will become true :
[compose page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stwNz.png)

[Api Route For Sent Mails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTwhu.png)

Anyone know what's the problem ??

I tried to change views.py or my JS or other files but because the harvard site told only do this project with JS, HTML and css i figured it's not the django files bugs.